# Temporarily pause an SQS worker tier app

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat7, amazon-sqs, worker, amazon-sns

I have an SQS Worker Tier beanstalk application listening to a queue. If we encounter any issues, for example a database crash, is there a way for us to temporarily stop the worker tier from working that queue without having to terminate the environment and rebuilding it again when we want to resume?

One hack I guess would be for us to point it to an empty queue, but I'd rather avoid that type of thing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For anybody who is in the same boat as me, I just want to post my own, inelegant solution.

We have created another SQS Queue, and whenever we want to turn off the processing of messages, we just update the worker tier app to point to this new queue. It isn't clean, but it does what we need.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to just leave it as is. In case of database crash, or any other error, your application will return for example 500 instead of 200 and message will be returned back to the queue for future processing.

Comment: The problem we have with this is that we set a maximum number of retries to 1. When a message is consumed it makes changes to the database across several different transactions. If One of those transactions falls over, or an exception is thrown, we don't want that message to be consumed again, so instead it is sent to our Dead Letter Queue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but you can add a delivery delay to SQS queue: right click the queue -> configure queue -> set `Delivery Delay` up to 15 minutes. Any message will be received after this delay. This allows me to "pause" the queue for up to 15 minutes.

Answer (score -1):

You can terminate the environment and recreate it. In case you do not have a way to recreate same environment via just one command, take a look at: https://github.com/ThoughtWorksStudios/eb_deployer